# Correct form when talking about intersection of few roads

Tags: formality

I'm in the process of writing a thesis (in a different language). I was wondering if it is correct to say that there are 3 roads that intersect, and I am planning their reconstruction:

```
Reconstruction of intersection of A and B and C in X.
```

where A, B, and C are street names, and X is the name of a town.

Comment: **[intersection](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intersection)** A point at which two or more things intersect, especially a road junction.

Comment: "Junction" is another term.  "Intersection" is commonly used with streets, while "junction" is used with highways (which are streets that continue out of town to other towns).

Comment: @HotLicks You will not find "intersection" much used in the UK. It seems particularly appropriate in America where streets "intersect"  - often at right angles. Arguably they also "intersect" in Britain, but the word does not seem to fit, in the case of a road layout which follows tracks that were laid down centuries ago.

Comment: If the junction is to be rebuilt, the result may no longer be an intersection (for example, it could become a roundabout).

Comment: You are planning to rebuild them. Not reconstruct them. The only way to do three roads meeting, is using a **rotary** or **roundabout** (as Anton said). Basic geometry. "A roundabout will be built at the point where A, B and C meet."

Comment: I think this is a case where US English is going to differ from UK, etc. English.  I think it's also a case where the terms of art in Civil Engineering (at least here in the US) are somewhat different from casual speech.  Who is the intended audience of your translation?

Comment: Why have you omitted the definite article?

Comment: @Lambie There are plenty of intersections in my town where three streets meet and are not roundabouts. For example a single through street with a cross-street that has two different names.

Comment: @Theodore Yes, and guess who has done a lot of road building texts from French and Spanish to English? Generally, unless 3 existing roads converge into a space, which is round, there is no intersection. intersections are for four roads.

Answer (score 1):

The list of roads in the intersection is a list, and should be treated like one.

> We are going to reconstruct the intersection of Alpha Street, Beta Road and Gamma Avenue in Greektown.

As others say, you need a verb to make this a correct sentence and should add a definite article before "intersection".

Comment: This is an acceptable use of *intersection*, since it’s road building and not geometry. We talk about Times Square as being at the intersection of Broadway and 42nd, but 7th avenue goes through there as well. The Wikipedia article shows multiple terms and their usage https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_Square

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all "Reconstruction of intersection of A and B and C in X." is not a sentence because it has no finite verb.

Also, it is not completely clear whether you are reconstructing the roads in general or just the place where they intersect.

If you are reconstructing the intersection of the three roads, then the way you wrote is ok, but there must be a finite verb to make a complete sentence (and a fragment makes no sense here).

Comment: Also note that you (correctly) snuck a “the” in before *intersection*.

Comment: titles do not have to be complete sentences. That said, reconstruction is not the right term in road building. rebuilding is. Also, three roads do not intersect.